# How do I count the currently selected option from the top?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

For example:

```
<select id="my-select">
  <option id="iun">Option 1</option>
  <option id="sdd">Option 2</option>
  <option id="ert" select="selected">Option 3</option>
  <option id="tyu">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

using jQuery?
I have a straightforward solution and was wondering if there is anything neater out there?

```
var count = 0;
var flag = true;
jQuery("#my-select").children().each(function() {
  if (flag) {
   count++;
   flag = (jQuery(this).attr("selected") !== undefined ? false : true); 
  }
});
console.log(count);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYP4W/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `index()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TRGKC/

```
$('#my-select option:selected').index()
```

Additionally, either of these would work:

```
$('#my-select').prop('selectedIndex')
$('#my-select')[0].selectedIndex
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! index makes sense too, since $('#my-select option:selected') is dealing with an object...cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the index of the selected option.This should do it:

```
 $("#my-select").attr("selectedIndex");
```

Or

```
 document.getElementById("my-select").selectedIndex;
```

Comment: `selectedIndex` is not an attribute and jQuery object doesn't have `selectedIndex` property, you are on the right track, but missing `.prop()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected option, do this:

```
var elementSelected = jQuery("#my-select option:selected");
```